# Spark Dataframe join 2 dataframes shows column missing error

Tags: apache-spark

Spark Dataframe join 2 dataframes shows column missing error

Spark Dataframe code:

```
x.join(y, x.col("sid").equalTo(y.col("tid")));
```

shows missing attributes `sid`, `tid` but both attributes do exist in hive tables.

Comment: Please share x.printSchema and y.printSchema

Comment: X
sid: string (nullable = true)
  name: string (nullable = true)
  lname: string (nullable = true)
  age: integer (nullable = true)
  role: string (nullable = true)
  dept: integer (nullable = true) 
 
Y
  tid: string (nullable = true)
  sales: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)

Comment: What's the version of Spark? Can you edit your question and add the error? That'd be so much helpful.